# How to dealloc memory of an array in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I created 150 UIwebviews and stored in an NSArray called myArray .After using those webviews , I do not need those 150 webviews .  Then I created another 100 UIWebViews and stored in myArray. I thought first 150 webviews will be automatically deallocated. But when i checked in Instruments , 250 web views are alive. How to release the memory manually ? I am using ARC. So I am not able to use release method.Please advise.

Comment: It surely depends at which point in the program you saw that memory still live. Unless you have a cyclic reference with any of the webviews/ `NSArray`, ARC should manage it nicely.

Comment: On addition to removing the web views from the array, if you had added them to a view, did you remove them from their superview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`[NSMutableArray removeAllObjects]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeAllObjects):

```
NSMutableArray *webViews = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    [webViews addObject:[self createWebView]];

[webViews removeAllObjects];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    [webViews addObject:[self createWebView]];
```

Comment: Not really on topic with this question, but why you use new instead of alloc init?

Comment: @LordZsolt To save typing and it looks neater; otherwise the two styles are identical.

Answer (score 1):

When adding an object to an array, it gets retained - so you need to empty the array to release the objects.

Incidentally, a UIWebView is a very heavy object.  You might consider using *one* UIWebView, and storing NSURLs in the array, loading them into the UIWebView as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create an autorelease pool around the code that uses the UIWebViews.  Something like this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Create and use your UIWebViews here.  Put them into an array, do whatever you want with them
}

// When you exit the @autoreleasepool block, the objects you created inside the block will be freed
```